# I have a Error Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '_GameDetailsPageState.build.<anonymous closure>

Tags: flutter

I am currently creating comments in the app that the user will be able to do and after doing the function I get this error and I don't know how to fix it.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEx6K.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbLph.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa4vg.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SPQR.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wxag.png

I searched for similar errors but those solutions did not help me

CustomTextField

```
    class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  String? hint;
  final TextEditingController commentController;
  final Function(String)? onSubmit;

  CustomTextField(
      {this.hint, required this.onSubmit, required this.commentController});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: commentController,
            onSubmitted: onSubmit,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "$hint",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple.shade200, width: 0)),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2.0))),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comments List

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import '../../../../../assets/paidwork_icons.dart';
import '../../../../../common/utils/paidwork_colors.dart';

class CommentsList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Comment> comments;
  CommentsList(this.comments);

  @override
  State<CommentsList> createState() => _CommentsListState();
}

class _CommentsListState extends State<CommentsList> {
  int likes = 0;
  int dislikes = 0;

  void giveLike() {
    setState(() {
      if (likes == 0) {
        likes++;
      } else {
        likes--;
      }
    });
  }

  void giveDisLike() {
    setState(() {
      if (dislikes == 0) {
        dislikes++;
      } else {
        dislikes--;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      child: widget.comments.isEmpty
          ? Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'No comments added yet!',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/waiting.png',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 400,
                        height: 235,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: PaidworkColors.lightWhite,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 8,
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                              child: Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width: 50,
                                    child: Image(image: AssetImage('')),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 10,
                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              'Maciej',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                                  fontSize: 15),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              width: 10,
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd').format(
                                                  widget.comments[index].date),
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.grey,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Icon(
                                              PaidworkIcons
                                                  .paidwork_icon_chart_alt,
                                              size: 30,
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              width: 10,
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        width: 320,
                                        child: Text(
                                          widget.comments[index].description,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                              fontSize: 14),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                          width: 320,
                                          child: Row(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                child: Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      likes.toString(),
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: PaidworkColors
                                                              .lightUnactive),
                                                    ),
                                                    GestureDetector(
                                                      onTap: () => giveLike(),
                                                      child: Icon(
                                                        PaidworkIcons
                                                            .paidwork_icon_heroicons_hand_like,
                                                        color: PaidworkColors
                                                            .lightUnactive,
                                                      ),
                                                    )
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 20,
                                              ),
                                              Container(
                                                child: Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      '${dislikes}',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: PaidworkColors
                                                              .lightUnactive),
                                                    ),
                                                    GestureDetector(
                                                      onTap: () {
                                                        giveDisLike();
                                                      },
                                                      child: Icon(
                                                        PaidworkIcons
                                                            .paidwork_icon_heroicons_hand_dislike,
                                                        color: PaidworkColors
                                                            .lightUnactive,
                                                      ),
                                                    )
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          )),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: widget.comments.length,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Functions

```
      void _startAddNewTransaction(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        return AddingCommentForm(
            commentController: commentController,
            userCommentAvatar: 'assets/images/account_game_avatar.png',
            userCommentUsername: 'Maciej',
            userCommentDate: '21.12.2222',
            addYourReview: () {},
            cancelReview: () {},
            addTx: _addNewTransaction);
      },
    );
  }

  final List<Comment> _userComments = [];
  void _addNewTransaction(String txDescription, String txDifficulty) {
    final newTx = Comment(
      description: txDescription,
      difficulty: txDifficulty,
      date: DateTime.now(),
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    );
    setState(() {
      _userComments.add(newTx);
    });
  }

  bool openAddReviewForm = false;

  void addReview() {
    setState(() {
      openAddReviewForm = !openAddReviewForm;
    });
  }

   
      final TextEditingController commentController = TextEditingController();

  void submitData() {
    final enteredDescription = commentController.text;

    if (enteredDescription.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    widget.addTx(
      enteredDescription,
    );

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

Comment: Please can edit you your question to directly insert code instead of using images? it will be easier for everyone to understand your issue.

Comment: @EricTaix Hey I have already corrected the question